# Grails unit testing working in different way

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy, grails-2.0

I am using grails 2.3.6 version . I have two domain class as below

```
class Profile {

  String name

  static belongsTo = Student
}


class Student {
Profile profile
Integer enrolmentNumber
}
```

I am trying to create one to one unidirectional relationship . The problem is I have written a unit test case

```
@TestFor(Student)
@Mock([Profile,Student])
class StudentSpec extends Specification {

void "test save Student"() {
    when :"Student details"
    Profile profile = new Profile(name:"Test")
    Student student = new Student(enrolmentNumber: 10,profile:profile)

    then : " Student should be saved"
    assertNotNull(student.save(flush: true))
    assertNotNull(profile.id)

    when:"When I delete the student"
    student.delete()

    then:"Profile should also deleted"
    assertNull Profile.findById(profile.id)
}
}
```

test is failing at the last line "Profile.findById(profile.id)" saying profile is found. As per my understanding when I have "belongsTo" then cascading should happen ,I mean when I delete the Student, Profile should also be delete . But its not happening .

Instead of creating a unit test , I used the same code in Integration test , its working correctly.

Not Sure what I am doing wrong. Or my understanding is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
   student.delete(flush:true)
```

Comment: No , its not working . I am getting the same error saying "Expected: <null> but was: Profile : 1"